# How to change the text of a "label for" using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="id_about">Profile</label>
```

How do I change this using JavaScript or jQuery? I want to only change this instance to replace profile with something else like About. I know how to change all "Profile" word from my website. But I only want to change this particular specific instance.

Comment: It's well worth your time to spend an hour or two reading through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and you'll probably get that time back within a week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search using attributes:

```
$("label[for=id_about]").html("new text here"); // or .text("new text here")
```

Remember that jQuery lets you use the full power of [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to find elements on the page (it even adds some of its own, but in general try to stick to official ones).

---

For anyone who doesn't use jQuery, you can still use the full range of CSS selectors on [any modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) (and IE8) via `querySelector` (find the first matching element, or `null` if no match) or `querySelectorAll` (get a `NodeList` of matching elements, which might be empty):

```
document.querySelector("label[for=id_about]").innerHTML = "new text here";
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution without JQuery, working with any browser.
Supposing this is part of your HTML:

```
<label id="myLabel" for="myTextField">my label text</label>
<input type="text" id="myTextField"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

This is the change() function to alter the label content:

```
function change(){
    var labelText = document.getElementById('myLabel');
    labelText.innerHTML = "new label text";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/6678/)

Comment: the OP hasn't mentioned whether ID is available. the attribute to search is 'for'

Comment: label id is visible in my fiddle. Anyway I add it to the answer.

Comment: *"This is the solution without JQuery"* No, this is the solution without jQuery: `document.querySelector("label[for=id_about]").innerHTML = "text here";` All modern browsers have `querySelector`, as do some non-modern ones (IE8, for example).